# Query date from user, use today's date if user press enter

Tags: c, if-statement, time, fgets

In a C-program I am trying to query user for a date which shall be put into a char-array in a structure (*pIndex->startDate*). If the date is today's date the user should only need to press enter - and if the date is some other, the user will have to type it in.

The input is done by fgets. What I think is that I'll check if the user input is equal  '\n' – in that case I set the array equal to today's date. If not, the array will be whatever the user typed.

To find the date (in general), I use:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
```

..and I have a temp char-array for the if-statement:

```
char temp_date[11]="2014-01-01";  //initialized with something, guess there is a better solution
```

I have tried the following:

```
    printf("Enter start date (press Enter for todays date) > ");
    fgets(pIndex->startDate, MAXDATE, stdin);
        if (pIndex->startDate=='\n'){
        sprintf (temp_date, "%d-%02d-%02d", t->tm_year+1900, t->tm_mon+1, t->tm_mday);
            (pIndex->startDate)==temp_date;
        }
/*Check the result*/
    printf("CHECK TEMP_DATE: %s\n> ",temp_date);
    system("pause");
```

However, the only thing that appears in the output is the value char temp_date was initialized with: *2014-01-01*

Is this a wrong approach? Anyone knows a better (working) way?

Comment: what is this `(pIndex->startDate)==temp_date;`?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `if (pIndex->startDate[0]=='\n')` instead of `if (pIndex->startDate=='\n')`? Also,you are doing comparison instead of assignment in the line iharob has pointed out in his comment.

Comment: @CoolGuy pIndex->startDate[0] was indeed the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @iharob, the temp_date seemed to be unnecessary, it was an attempt to temporary place the value. But I could of course do without. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value fo `MAXDATE`?  What is the definition of field `startDate`?

Comment: @chux, MAXDATE is 11, startDate is a char.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
size_t length;

printf("Enter start date (press Enter for todays date) > ");
fgets(pIndex->startDate, MAXDATE, stdin);
/* this is wrong */
// if (pIndex->startDate=='\n'){
length = strlen(pIndex->startDate);
if ((length == 1) && (pIndex->startDate[length - 1] == '\n')) {
    sprintf(temp_date, "%d-%02d-%02d", t->tm_year+1900, t->tm_mon+1, t->tm_mday);
    strcpy(pIndex->startDate, temp_date);
}
/*Check the result*/
printf("CHECK TEMP_DATE: %s\n> ",temp_date);
system("pause");
```

Comment: `if (pIndex->startDate[0] == '\n') {` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with call to `fgets()`.  The destination is the wrong type. The buffer size needed to read "2014-01-01" will certainly include a newline `'\n'` and null character `'\0'` or at least 12 `char`.  Also good idea to check the result of `fgets()`.

```
// Problem code
// MAXDATE is 11, startDate is a char
#define MAXDATE 11
struct {
  char startDate;
} *pIndex;
...
fgets(pIndex->startDate, MAXDATE, stdin);

// Recommend
#define MAXDATE 11
struct {
  char startDate[MAXDATE + 1];
} *pIndex;
...
if (fgets(pIndex->startDate, MAXDATE, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
```

To check is the input begins with `'\n'`, use

```
if (pIndex->startDate[0] == '\n') {
```